# How to get the host app's package name from my custom keyboard?

Tags: android, package, android-softkeyboard, android-package-managers

Inside a custom Android keyboard app, is there any way of getting the name of the package that the keyboard is currently running in (i.e the name of the app with the edit field)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when your keyboard gets called/ created:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
String packageName = componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

And you need the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Hope it helped.